# Regular expression: No results even though confirmed in regex tester

Tags: regex, arduino

I want to isolate `HDMI` from the string `>*sour=?#*SOUR=HDMI#` (`HDMI` varies and can have different lengths). I came up with this regular expression to do that: `(?<=SOUR=)[^#]*`. Using [this](https://regex101.com/r/cLNbKr/2) online regex tester, I confirmed that this is in fact working.

[image]

In my Arduino code, I'm using [Nick Gammon's RegExp library](https://github.com/nickgammon/Regexp). I followed Nick's  [documentation](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11063) and this code runs fine and finds two matches, just like in his example. However, when I insert my above `Target` and `Match` parameters, the `Match` method returns no matches (i.e. `Serial.println("no match")` is executed). Any advice?

Here's my code:

```
#include <Regexp.h>

void setup ()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  MatchState ms;
  ms.Target (">*sour=?#*SOUR=HDMI#");

  char result = ms.Match ("(?<=SOUR=)[^#]*");
  if (result == REGEXP_MATCHED)
  {
    char buf [100]  
    Serial.print ("Captures: ");
    Serial.println (ms.level);

    for (int j = 0; j < ms.level; j++)
      {
      Serial.print ("Capture number: ");
      Serial.println (j, DEC);
      Serial.print ("Text: '");
      Serial.print (ms.GetCapture (buf, j));
      Serial.println ("'");
      }
  }
  else if (result == REGEXP_NOMATCH)
  {
    Serial.println("no match");
  }
}

void loop () {}
```

Comment: The library you are using does not suppport lookbehinds. Use a capturing group, `"SOUR=([^#]*)"`

Comment: That did it. Thanks A LOT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you are using does not suppport lookbehinds.

You may solve the problem using a capturing group:

```
 char result = ms.Match ("SOUR=([^#]*)");
```